# How to unlock password protected MicroSD?

Tags: passwords, memory-card

Recently I locked a MicroSD memory card from my Nokia 6210 (S60v3) and forgot the password.
It was not much of a problem but today I formatted the phone and it is now asking for password. I tried to connect it to PC but it doesn't show up.
Is there some way I can access its content?

Comment: Got similar problem. :-) I doubt the content can be accessible in some reasonable easy way. The only thing I'm trying to accomplish is reset the password!...

Answer (score 5):

I hope the following solutions will help you. From https://sites.google.com/site/way2smarthacker …

> It is common knowledge that if the password for the card is lost then
>   it will be blocked for further use. In such a situation, the **user
>   can interface his mobile with the PC using Bluetooth or Infrared and
>   make the changes and find the password in the file obtained
>   thereafter.....**
>
> ***Solution number one***
>
> - Go to file manager on your mobile,
> - In the "Settings" option,
> - Choose system folders,
> - In the "System" folder, there's a file called "MMCSTORE",
> - Send that to your PC using IR/Bluetooth,
> - Then open it in notepad.
> - The password you need for your memory card is in that file
>
> ***Solution number two:***
>
> 1. Insert card into your phone or through card reader but don't access it through phone.
> 2. Run FExplorer and Open the path C:\system.
> 3. You will find a file called mmcstore ,rename the file mmcstore.txt
> 4. Copy that file(mmcstore.txt) to your pc and open that file in notepad.
> 5. You will find your password in that file.(MMC)   [you can download FExplorer here](http://www.4shared.net/fexplorer)
>
> For Micro SD:
>
> Put the card in any E series mobile or N95 etc and format it it will
>   not ask for password.